# Javascript change for loop variable from within the loop

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop, continue

I have a for loop like so

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i += 4) {
    // code with i;
}
```

I would like to change the value of `i` to a certain value from within the loop. I am aware you could use `continue` to change the value of `i` after evaluating the final-expression, but what if I wanted to change the value of i to something more specific like 40?

Here's one of my attempts

```
loop:
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i += 4) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 40; i++) {
        continue loop;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why can't you just assign it the value you want? It's just another variable after all. Just make sure you don't set it in such a way that you'll infinitely loop.

Comment: I have a feeling that this may be an X/Y Problem.

Comment: I see that I could've reassigned it now. And yes this is one question I'm looking an answer to in order to solve a bigger problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change i directly:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i += 4) {
    i = 15000;
}
```

This would exit the loop immediately, but you could do whatever you wanted.

You should read up on [function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) to understand how this stuff works. For loops are  bit different from functions in that they're a language construct but the same theory of scope holds true.

Comment: I don't want to exit the loop after I change the i value though. Is there another way of doing this? I'll go read function scope and look.

Comment: nvm I see why it would exit the loop imeediately. Because 15000 < 100.

Answer (score 1):

The [scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzt2dkta%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) of increment variable is always available inside the loop block, this allows you  to access increment variable inside the loop block.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i += 4) {
    if (condition)  i = 40 ;
    /* put any condition to avoid the infinite loop and continue with your rest of code */
}
```

Comment: You should add some condition to avoid the infinite loop,

Comment: @cookiemonster definitely this will not be the complete loop he must be doing something inside the loop

Comment: Yeah, just wanted to make sure that some beginner out there didn't run the code and freeze their browser. ;-)

Comment: Yea I'm doing something else within the loop, but I just got stuck on this part.

Comment: share your complete loop and tell us what you want to do

Comment: I would put everything up, but I'm solving a puzzle atm and think it would be too long and a new topic onto itself.